# grumble.js, jQuery plugin (Bubble popups): how to make it not polute my document body with unremovable trash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, popup

I want to show a popup many on click. I want that many to be in a bubble. So I created a demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sR9zG/7/). But that [Bubble generator plugin](http://jamescryer.github.com/grumble.js/) i use tends to keep tons of trash in the DOM each time it shows a popup. Well so I tried to destroy trash via

```
        $('.grumble-text').remove();
        $('.grumble').remove();
        $('.grumble-button').remove();
```

But it somehow brakes it at all=( So how to change [grumble-bubble popup plugin code](http://jamescryer.github.com/grumble.js/) to make it either keep DOM clean or at least make plugin independent of trash it creates?

Comment: Will you have multiple opened bubbles?

Comment: In that case wouldn't be easier to build your own bubble script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've recently updated the plugin to provide better control of positioning and angle.  The update also persists the grumble, invoking the plugin more than once on an element will not create extra left over DOM.

Try updating to the latest code. The code below should now work as you expect.

```
var html = ''
    +'<a href="#me" target="_blank">Download me</a>'
    +'<br/>'
    +'<a href="#edit">Edit me</a>'
    +'<br/>'
    +'<a href="#delete">Delete me</a>';

var $grumble = $('#grumble3');

$grumble.mouseup(function(eventObj) {
    $grumble.grumble({
        text: html ,
        angle: (Math.random() * 360 + 150),
        distance: 30,
        hideOnClick: true,
        onShow: function() {
            $grumble.addClass("hilight");
        },
        onBeginHide: function() {
            $grumble.removeClass("hilight");
        }
    });
}).mousedown(function() {
    $grumble.addClass("hilight");
});
```

Thanks for your interest.  If there are any further problems please raise them as bugs on the github page. https://github.com/jamescryer/grumble.js

Answer (score 2):

Use the `grumble` and `button` parameters on the `onHide` callback like this:

```
$('#grumble').grumble({
    text: 'Whoaaa, this is a lot of text that i couldn\'t predict',
    angle: 85,
    distance: 50,
    showAfter: 4000,
    hideAfter: 2000,
    onHide: function(grumble, button) {
        grumble.bubble.remove();
        grumble.text.remove();
        button && button.remove();
    }
});
```

This allows you to remove only the "trash" (I prefer "leftovers") associated with that specific tooltip/popup/bubble.  Note that `button` only exists if `hasHideButton` is `true`, hence the `button &&` existence check.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to remove it? Is the 'trash' causing problems with browser performance?

In general, the only way to do this is to dig into the plugin source and add a function to remove the plugin, if one is not already present. If you just remove the related DOM elements you will leave behind references to them and events handlers that access them.